# Extract knots, basis, coefficients and predictions for P-splines in adaptive smooth

Tags: r, spline, mgcv

I'm using the *mgcv* package to fit some polynomial splines to some data via:

```
x.gam <- gam(cts ~ s(time, bs = "ad"), data = x.dd,
             family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

I'm trying to extract the functional form of the fit. `x.gam` is a `gamObject`, and I've been reading the documentation but haven't found enough information in order to manually reconstruct the fitted function.

- `x.gam$smooth` contains information about whether the knots have been placed;
- `x.gam$coefficients` gives the spline coefficients, but I don't know what order polynomial splines are used and looking in the code has not revealed anything.

**Is there a neat way to extract the knots, coefficients and basis used so that one can manually reconstruct the fit?**

Comment: It doesn't say whether it is using bsplines or psplines and in the latter case what order they are

Comment: Hey Zheyuan, its a great answer, im just filling in the gaps before I accept it. Could you tell me what the mathematical form of the basis is?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I take the following example from `?adaptive.smooth` to show you where you can find information you want. Note that though this example is for Gaussian data rather than Poisson data, only the link function is different; all the rest are just standard.

```
 x <- 1:1000/1000  # data between [0, 1]
 mu <- exp(-400*(x-.6)^2)+5*exp(-500*(x-.75)^2)/3+2*exp(-500*(x-.9)^2)
 y <- mu+0.5*rnorm(1000)
 b <- gam(y~s(x,bs="ad",k=40,m=5))
```

Now, all information on smooth construction is stored in `b$smooth`, we take it out:

```
smooth <- b$smooth[[1]]  ## extract smooth object for first smooth term
```

**knots:**

`smooth$knots` gives you location of knots.

```
> smooth$knots
 [1] -0.081161 -0.054107 -0.027053  0.000001  0.027055  0.054109  0.081163
 [8]  0.108217  0.135271  0.162325  0.189379  0.216433  0.243487  0.270541
[15]  0.297595  0.324649  0.351703  0.378757  0.405811  0.432865  0.459919
[22]  0.486973  0.514027  0.541081  0.568135  0.595189  0.622243  0.649297
[29]  0.676351  0.703405  0.730459  0.757513  0.784567  0.811621  0.838675
[36]  0.865729  0.892783  0.919837  0.946891  0.973945  1.000999  1.028053
[43]  1.055107  1.082161
```

Note, three external knots are placed beyond each side of `[0, 1]` to construct spline basis.

**basis class**

`attr(smooth, "class")` tells you the type of spline. As you can read from `?adaptive.smooth`, for `bs = ad`, `mgcv` use P-splines, hence you get "pspline.smooth".

`mgcv` use 2nd order pspline, you can verify this by checking the difference matrix `smooth$D`. Below is a snapshot:

```
> smooth$D[1:6,1:6]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1   -2    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1   -2    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1   -2    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1   -2    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1   -2
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

**coefficients**

You have already known that `b$coefficients` contain model coefficients:

```
beta <- b$coefficients
```

Note this is a named vector:

```
> beta
(Intercept)      s(x).1      s(x).2      s(x).3      s(x).4      s(x).5 
 0.37792619 -0.33500685 -0.30943814 -0.30908847 -0.31141148 -0.31373448 
     s(x).6      s(x).7      s(x).8      s(x).9     s(x).10     s(x).11 
-0.31605749 -0.31838050 -0.32070350 -0.32302651 -0.32534952 -0.32767252 
    s(x).12     s(x).13     s(x).14     s(x).15     s(x).16     s(x).17 
-0.32999553 -0.33231853 -0.33464154 -0.33696455 -0.33928755 -0.34161055 
    s(x).18     s(x).19     s(x).20     s(x).21     s(x).22     s(x).23 
-0.34393354 -0.34625650 -0.34857906 -0.05057041  0.48319491  0.77251118 
    s(x).24     s(x).25     s(x).26     s(x).27     s(x).28     s(x).29 
 0.49825345  0.09540020 -0.18950763  0.16117012  1.10141701  1.31089436 
    s(x).30     s(x).31     s(x).32     s(x).33     s(x).34     s(x).35 
 0.62742937 -0.23435309 -0.19127140  0.79615752  1.85600016  1.55794576 
    s(x).36     s(x).37     s(x).38     s(x).39 
 0.40890236 -0.20731309 -0.47246357 -0.44855437
```

**basis matrix / model matrix / linear predictor matrix (lpmatrix)**

You can get model matrix from:

```
mat <- predict.gam(b, type = "lpmatrix")
```

This is an `n-by-p` matrix, where `n` is the number of observations, and `p` is the number of coefficients. This matrix has column name:

```
> head(mat[,1:5])
  (Intercept)    s(x).1    s(x).2      s(x).3      s(x).4
1           1 0.6465774 0.1490613 -0.03843899 -0.03844738
2           1 0.6437580 0.1715691 -0.03612433 -0.03619157
3           1 0.6384074 0.1949416 -0.03391686 -0.03414389
4           1 0.6306815 0.2190356 -0.03175713 -0.03229541
5           1 0.6207361 0.2437083 -0.02958570 -0.03063719
6           1 0.6087272 0.2688168 -0.02734314 -0.02916029
```

The first column is all 1, giving intercept. While `s(x).1` suggests the first basis function for `s(x)`. If you want to view what individual basis function look like, you can plot a column of `mat` against your variable. For example:

```
plot(x, mat[, "s(x).20"], type = "l", main = "20th basis")
```

[image: basis]

**linear predictor**

If you want to manually construct the fit, you can do:

```
pred.linear <- mat %*% beta
```

Note that this is exactly what you can get from `b$linear.predictors` or

```
predict.gam(b, type = "link")
```

**response / fitted values**

For non-Gaussian data, if you want to get response variable, you can apply inverse link function to linear predictor to map back to original scale.

Family information are stored in `gamObject$family`, and `gamObject$family$linkinv` is the inverse link function. The above example will certain gives you identity link, but for your fitted object `x.gam`, you can do:

```
x.gam$family$linkinv(x.gam$linear.predictors)
```

Note this is the same to `x.gam$fitted`, or

```
predict.gam(x.gam, type = "response").
```

---

**Other links**

I have just realized that there were quite a lot of similar questions before.

1. [This answer by Gavin Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15584541/4891738) is great, for `predict.gam( , type = 'lpmatrix')`.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021408/4891738) is about `predict.gam(, type = 'terms')`.

But anyway, the best reference is always `?predict.gam`, which includes extensive examples.