# mgcv: how to specify interaction between smooth and factor?

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv

In R, I would like to fit a gam model with categorical variables. I thought I could do it like with (cat is the categorical variable).

```
lm(data = df, formula = y ~ x1*cat + x2 + x3);
```

But I can't do things like :

```
gam(data = df, formula = y ~ s(x1)*cat + s(x2) + x3)
```

but the following works:

```
gam(data = df, formula = y ~ cat + s(x1) + s(x2) + x3)
```

How do I add a categorical variable to just one of the splines?

Comment: This question is off topic here because it concentrates on functions in R.

Comment: The thing you appear to be trying in the second chunk of code (and interaction between a categorical variable and a smooth), can be accomplished using the `by` function. i.e. `s(x,by=cat)` will fit a separate smooth for each level of `cat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the comments has more or less told you how. Use `by` variable:

```
s(x1, by = cat)
```

This creates the "factor smooth" smoothing class `fs`, where a smooth function of `x1` is created for each factor level. Smoothing parameters are also duplicated but not linked, so they are estimated indecently. You can set

```
s(x1, by = cat, id = 0)
```

to use a single smoothing parameter for all "sub smooths".

Also note that contrast does not apply to factor but smooth function is still subject to centering constraint. What this means is that you need to specify factor variable as a fixed effect, too:

```
s(x1, by = cat) + cat
```

Comment: Minor clarification: `s(x1, by = cat)` *doesn't* create a `"fs"` class smooth - if it did you wouldn't need `+ cat` for the centring. If you want what mgcv calls an `"fs"` smooth then you need `s(x1, cat, bs = "fs")` (and no parametric `cat` term).