# mgcv: how to specify interaction between smooth and factor? part II

Tags: r, mgcv

There is a question with the same title, however, I hope this question is also of interest [and personally I'd like to know the answer].

First, I will specify a dataset with one continuous and one factor covariate:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 50
u1 <- sample(c(1,2), n, replace = TRUE) 
u1 <- factor(u1)
u2 <- runif(n)
data <- data.frame(u1, u2)
```

I don't want to run a `gam` model, but only to create the design matrix. I have considered 2 ways.

First,

```
a<-mgcv::s(u2,k=5,bs="ps",by=u1)
b<- mgcv::smoothCon(a,data=data,absorb.cons=TRUE)
```

However,

```
b[[1]]$X[u1==2,]
```

consists of only 0's.

Second,

```
a<- mgcv::s(u1,u2,k=5,bs="ad")
b<- mgcv::smoothCon(a,data=data,absorb.cons=TRUE)
```

However, it gives me an error message. `Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors`

How can this problem be resolved? I'd like to have the design matrix that models a smooth term separately for each level of factor `u1` [binary, as here, or otherwise].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to run a `gam` model, but only to create the design matrix.
>
> I'd like to have the design matrix that models a smooth term separately for each level of factor `u1`.

```
library(mgcv)

set.seed(1)
n <- 50
u1 <- sample(c(1,2), n, replace = TRUE) 
u1 <- factor(u1)
u2 <- runif(n)
data <- data.frame(u1, u2)
```

---

```
a <- s(u2, k = 5, bs = "ps", by = u1)
b <- smoothCon(a, data = data, absorb.cons = TRUE)
```

`smoothCon` produces a list of length `nlevels(u1)` for this factor "by" smooth. A Dummy matrix is created for `u1` (with two columns in this example), and each column is multiplied to the design matrix of `s(u2, l = 5, bs = "ps")`. So, `b[[1]]$X` is the design matrix for the first level, and `b[[2]]$X` is the one for the second level. You shouldn't be surprised that `b[[1]]$X[u1 == 2]` gives all zeros, as that is the design matrix for `u1 == 1`. You want to `cbind` those separate matrices together:

```
cbind(b[[1]]$X, b[[2]]$X)
```

Note that, because you have set `absorb.cons = TRUE`, the spline function is centered. I.e., mean of each level is constrained (not necessarily at 0 but is fixed at some value). A practical effect is that you then need to put `u1` in the model otherwise you can not model the group mean. In `mgcv`, you have to specify

```
s(u2, k = 5, bs = 'ps', by = u1) + u1
```

This is also mentioned in the Q & A you referenced: [mgcv: how to specify interaction between smooth and factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43330346/4891738). In your application outside `mgcv` you need be aware of this as well. So a complete model matrix should be

```
cbind(b[[1]]$X, b[[2]]$X, model.matrix(~ u1))
```